# Want to access a value in a dictionary which is inside a list inside another dictionary

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm using Python3 with the boto3 package and I'm running describe_instances() to describe all of my instances.  However the return type is a dictionary, now there are lists and other dictionaries inside the dictionary.

What I want to do for example is return only the "InstanceId" string or if I could return the entire "Instances" list that wouldn't be bad either.

```
ec2 = boto3.client(Make connection here)
response = ec2.describe_instances()
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(response)
```

The return type and the response code can be found here.  http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of all InstanceIDs as a list with something like

```
import itertools
instance_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i.get("InstanceId") for i in r.get("Instances", [])] for r in response['Reservations']]))
```

Comment: This works exactly how I would want it to work.  However could you explain the syntax a bit.  Complete noob at Python here.

Comment: `i.get("key", default)` returns a default value if the key does not exist in the dictionary; `[f(i) for i in x]` is a list comprehension expression, which builds a list by iterating through and evaluating f(i) for each element of x. Thus, it's more or less equivalent to `the_list = []; for i in x: the_list.append(f(i))`, but without ever assigning that list to a variable.